# Update data in mysql with html form inside jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I need a help in making a page where you can see data from a mysql query. Every row is echoed as a `div` with a unique `id`.

```
<div class="column" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

It has the same id as the data in the mysql database. Every `div` contains an edit button:

```
<a href="edit_column.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="edit">Edit</a>
```

After clicking 'edit', a jQuery script is executed:

```
$('.edit').on('click', function() {
            var url = this.href;
            var dialog = $("#dialog");
            if ($("#dialog").length == 0) {
                dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
            }
            dialog.load(
                url,
                {},
                function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    dialog.dialog();
                }
                );
            return false;
        })
```

Then, a dialog box pops up with a HTML form and I even managed to put MySQL data into that form to edit it. But now I don't know how to continue. How should I continue to update the data in the database? I know how to update it with PHP and I even have a PHP script `update_column.php` but I don't know how to execute it from the dialog box and refresh the respective `div` element with updated data without refreshing the whole page in the browser. In `edit_column.php`, I only have the HTML form and the PHP script which returns data from the MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you have to do is to add event to submit the edit form on one of your items in the ajax form you got from the first ajax call,
you will also have to save the edit id you can do it by save it to global var,

```
var editId;
$('.edit').on('click', function() {
        var url = this.href;
        editId = $(this).attr('id');
        var dialog = $("#dialog");
        if ($("#dialog").length == 0) {
            dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
        }
        dialog.load(
            url,
            {},
            function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                dialog.dialog();
            }
            );
        return false;
    });

/*
this is the event that will submit the ajax form
*/
    $('body').on('click', '#elementToSubmit', function() {
      formData = $('#ajaxForm').serialize();
      formData.id = editId;
      $.post('proccessEdit.php', formData, function(result) {// do something like hiding the modal or showing loading image

      });
    });
```

in your php file the one which generate the dynamic form for the specific id will have to look like this

```
<form id="ajaxForm">
<!-- some inputs -->
</form>
<!-- this will submit the ajaxForm -->
<a id="elementToSubmit">Save modifications</a>
```

Comment: #elementToSubmit is id of my form from dialog box?

Comment: this is the element that will generate the submission of the edit form, you have to use it this way because the form was build in ajax so the event will have to be attached to the body first

Comment: i dont really understand that #elementToSubmit i used your code but nothing my dialog box closes but data is not updated i dont use editId because i post ide in form as hidden input

Comment: I updated my answer hope it will make you understand it

Comment: well after editing the form after yours i think that <a> does nothing without href its just text after clicking on nothing happens even the dialog doesnt close

Comment: you have to check if clicking on the a will generate the post, it not suppose to do anything other then that, and in the comment you should hide the dialog "// do something like hiding the modal or showing loading image"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76281/discussion-between-talsibony-and-palci12).

Comment: your answer solved my problem atleast updating the data i will now play with ajax the fault was that i didnt catched id in php so it was my mistake thanks for your cooperation you are awesome

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you will need to use ajax, ajax calls can communicate to your server php script back and forth with out refreshing the page.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_php.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the data without reloading the page, you will need to use an ajax request. I see you use jQuery, so you can look at `jQuery.ajax()`.
Somehing like `$.ajax({ ... })`. I see you  have no problem finding how to use an API, and you can find the details here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You will have the URL set to an address where you send some params via POST, and then, at that URL, you will have a PHP function that will parse those params and get data from MySQL and return the data that you need in your JavaScript.

Comment: i have update_columm.php with php functions tu update mysql it excepts POST params so should i make after clicking on edit button in form should javascript execute update php function and then with ajax refresh updated div?

Comment: Yes, that would be the point of using AJAX. In your edit form, you would use event.preventDefault() on the submit button, or simply remove the submit button and trigger ajax on hitting enter. Using events there are lots of ways to solve your problem. You just need to choose one.